# Mark a question as "typical duplicate link"

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I just found this question on SO: [C# Same numbers in all 5 boxes and its suppose to be 5 different numbers in 5 different boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945322/c-same-numbers-in-all-5-boxes-and-its-suppose-to-be-5-different-numbers-in-5-dif), which is the typical "why doesn't my `new Random().Next(...)` produce different numbers when called many times" type of question.

However, to find a proper duplicate, that's a different story.

Would it be possible to find such a duplicate answer, and then mark it somehow, so that the next time you find a question and just *know* there is a duplicate for it, there would be a quicker way of finding it?

Comment: I wanted this as well today. Couldn't be arsed to find an exact dupe for something that's either closed or accepted in five minutes. Still, what would this mark do in practice?

Comment: I don't know, but some questions pop up with such regularity that any system is better than "find + browse N pages".

Comment: Perhaps just a tag-based shared link page for duplicates that pop up often would be enough. You go to the page, type in "random" in a search-box and find the 3 answers (for different types of problems, or different langues), and copy the link/id to the one you want. This could be limited to high-rep people anyway so as not to fill the list with unnecessary cruft, in which case it would become just as useless.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this to be a public repository, or more of a personal one? There are some existing facilities which, while not exactly what you might desire, do perform some degree of the needs.

If it's public, then the [tag based FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/faq) is partly derived from questions that receive the most links - which tend to be the ones that are the sources of duplicates. If the target question doesn't have the right tags, consider searching for the tags you are pretty sure are on the source question.

If it's personal, then you can technically use favorites to mark things that you're pretty sure will get asked frequently. Naturally, consider turning off favorites notification if this is the case. For out-of-engine solutions, also consider keeping a simple text file listing the IDs or URLs of questions you've encountered that you know someone will duplicate.

Comment: +1: All good ideas, none of which precludes any solution built into the platform :)

Comment: And I was thinking of a public list. I know I can use favorites, and since I use Google Chrome, which I've set up to synchronize all my bookmarks across all my computers, so much the better. But my bookmarks does not help the next guy that also thinks that there is probably a good, existing, duplicate, question with answers for the current question. All I'm asking is that you (SOIS) put it on a feature-request list, not that it is highly prioritized :)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar situation in this question here:

[Difference between a "public" class and an unmodified class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585043/difference-between-a-public-class-and-an-unmodified-class)

I've browsed through quite a few questions that deal with the same Java concept: visibility. They were all not "exact" duplicates (e.g. treating method visibility instead of class visibility, etc.), but they all sufficiently cover the subject in a way that the OP could have found the answer to their specific question themselves.

This happens quite often with questions by new users, so I tend not to spend the time to find the "exact" duplicate, but mark the duplicate as "almost-exact" instead, in the comments. If the question gets closed, the "Possible Duplicates" are referenced at the top of the question. Yet, I think your "typical duplicate" feature would be nice.